# Validation (unique) while editing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

Maybe this has already been asked, but I did not find it.

I have a validation in my post edit form:

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'content' => 'required',
]);
```

The problem is that if the user wants to change only the content, then the header validation (unique) will work and he will not be able to confirm the changes without changing the title.

How can this be solved?

UPD. I found [this](https://laravel.io/forum/04-18-2017-updating-another-user-and-ignoring-its-nameemail-when-validating), but is it posible to implement it without creating a new RequestController?

Comment: in edit page you will already have data so you can send those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case while updating the post you can ignore the current `post` id you are updating by specifying that id in the `unique` rule

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts,title,'.$post->id.'|max:255',
    'content' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: Not working dear, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unique in laravel works like this.

**unique: "tableName", "tableColumnName"**